# Use input instead of form on navbar search by bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code in my `navbar` by bootstrap4.

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" id="search">
      <input class="form-control form-control-sm mr-sm-2" name="search" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button onclick="clickSearch()" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0">Search</button>
</form>
```

This code is ok, but what I want to is not `submit` just call `clickSearch()`

So at first, I delete `<form>` tag but if so, the layout is broken.

I am thinking two solution.

1. How not to make layout broken with out `form` tag
2. Cancelling the form submit somewhow.(maybe workaround?)

Please help me ideas.

Comment: `type="button"` or `e.preventDefault`?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your form with div or do this as below.

```js
$( "button" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" id="search">
      <input class="form-control form-control-sm mr-sm-2" name="search" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0">Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `<form> ... </form>` with `<div> ... </div>`. It works!

Answer (score -1):

you can make it like this

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" >
  <input class="form-control" 
         name="search"  
         id="search" 
         type="text" 
         placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" >
  <button onclick="clickSearch()" 
          class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0">
      Search
  </button>
```

and get value

```
function clickSearch() {
        const searchValue = document.getElementById("search").value;
        console.log(searchValue)
}
```

Comment: What are you doing please explain.